# Embed YouTube video not showing on UICollectionView

Tags: embed, ios7, uicollectionviewcell

So another issue I'm having with UICollectionView.

This time I'm trying to show embed videos (YouTube) on a UICollectionViewCell.

The Embed method doesn't work, it gives me blank cells.

If I use the path directly, works, but it will show the whole page on Youtube instead of the video only.

Any idea what could it be?

Here's the code:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    L4VideoCell *videocell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"videoCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    videocell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    NSString *webpath = @"<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/rmx55fxRK5A?rel=0\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
    [videocell.webAudioView loadHTMLString:webpath baseURL:nil];


    return videocell;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the issue.

I'm not sure if this reason is valid but it worked for me.

Before, I was passing the baseURL:nil. I added my own base URL and it worked.

```
[webview loadHTMLString:"Embed URL from YouTube" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myurl.com"]];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am running into same issue. but adding baseURL didn't help. Was your baseUrl same as the one you used in loadHTMLString?